# Issues about Miranda's definition of the algebraic curve.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, riemann-surfaces

On Page 171 of Rick Miranda's *Algebraic Curves and Riemann Surfaces*, he gave Theorem 1.9 without a proof.

> **Definition 1.1.**  Let $S$ be a set of meromorphic functions on a compact Riemann surface $X$. We say that $S$ *separates points* of $X$ if for every pair of distinct points $p$ and $q$ in $X$ there is a meromorphic function $f \in S$ such that $f(p) \ne f(q)$. We say that $S$ *separates tangents* of $X$ if for every point $p \in X$ there is a meromorphic function $f \in S$ which has multiplicity one at $p$. A compact Riemann surface $X$ is an *algebraic curve* if the field $\mathcal{M}(X)$ of global meromorphic functions separates the points and tangents of $X$.

> The basic analytic result from which we will proceed is the following.
>
> **Theorem 1.9.** Every compact Riemann surface is an algebraic curve.

By reading Otto Forster's text I found the proof of separating points part (Corollary 14.13, Page 116):

> **14.13. Corollary.** Suppose $X$ is a compact Riemann surface and $a_1, \dots, a_n$ are distinct points on $X$. Then for any given complex numbers $c_1, \dots, c_n \in \mathbb{C}$, there exists a meromorphic function $f \in \mathscr{M}(X)$ such that $f(a_i) = c_i$ for $i = 1, \dots, n$.

but can anyone tell me how to prove the separating tangents part?

Comment: Right now, this question is not easily answerable by people who do not have these book open in front of them. That decreases the chance that you're going to get an answer. I would suggest adding more information to your post with an [edit]: at least the statement of the  theorem you're asking about, and more context (what Miranda has recently proven, Forster's approach, etc) would not hurt either.